# To read value from uploaded file and send it to url address

Tags: php, json

```
<? if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{

$f_name = $_FILES["filetoupload"]["name"];
$f_tmp = $_FILES["filetoupload"]["tmp_name"]; 
$store = "uploads/".$f_name;

if(move_uploaded_file($f_tmp,$store))
    echo "file uploaded successfully";
    echo"<br>";
}

$line = fgets($f_open);
echo $line;
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";
$furl ="$url"."$line";
echo "$furl";
$ch = curl_init("$furl");
$fp = fopen("example4.txt","w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '10.10.80.11:3128');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);


echo $json['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['types'][0];
echo $json['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['types'][1];

$data=json_decode($jsondata); 
$address=$data->results[0]->address_components; 
?>
```

bove mentioned program,

I'm trying to retrieve value line by line from uploaded file and concatenate the retrieving value with url,

But I got the error message..

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phpprog\upload_file_add.php on line 50...

Where is my mistake with the description...

Comment: can u plz let us know which line is your line number 50 in file upload_file_add.php?

Comment: where does `$f_open` comes from?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to check that your $jsondata variable is valid before using json_decode. It's probably you're receiving null in $data so it's no longer an object when you try to access its properties.
Use var_dump($data) after json_decode($jsondata) to verify you're receiving what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

you are giving us code that has variables that we don't know where they come from, like your `$f_open` and `$json`. You cannot use `fgets()` without opening the file with `fopen()`.

```
$f_name = $_FILES["filetoupload"]["name"];
$f_tmp = $_FILES["filetoupload"]["tmp_name"]; 
$store = "uploads/".$f_name;

if(move_uploaded_file($f_tmp,$store)){
   echo "file uploaded successfully";
   echo"<br>";
}
$f_open = fopen($store,"r");
$line = fgets($f_open);
echo $line;
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";
$furl ="$url"."$line";
echo "$furl";
```

reading a text file which contains `reading_files_with_PHP`
the above code displays

> reading_files_with_PHP 
>   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=reading_files_with_PHP